# Pretty URL for custom search for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search

I am using custom post types, I made custom search form for this posts and also I need the default search to be working the search URL is

`http://example.com/?search=advanced&name=bla&cost=00&somefiled=0&another_filed[1]=blabla&another_filed[2]=blablabla`

the excpeteced URL is

`example.com/searchadvanced/bla/00/0/blabla/blablabal`

I tried this

`wp_redirect( home_url( '/searchadvanced/' ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 'searchadvanced' ) ) );`

but not worked

So I need to change this URL to be pretty one

Comment: What are you expecting URLs will look like? Have you looked round at any other similar questions here? What have you tried?